# Issue with pytrends and latest update of Google Trends website

Tags: python

Seems like since the Google Trends webiste update, I haven't been able to use Pytrends at all.
Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks!

It's giving me error code 429 straight away.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have also encountered the same error. It would be beneficial if someone could communicate with the developer regarding this matter for assistance - I also think everyone facing the same: https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/561

Answer (score 2):

## Original Answer

[A comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75711314/issue-with-pytrends-and-latest-update-of-google-trends-website#comment133576850_75711314) led me to this [GitHub Issue from 8 March](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/561). The issue stems from March 2023 updates Google made to security on their end. Looks like Google is [making it harder to scrape trends in an update](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/561#issuecomment-1462435132), and they can tell who is using browser vs scraping. So, upping the number of `retries` in the `backoff_factor` won't necessarily work; it may be more about one's user type classification as a "scraper" vs "legit_user". This may stem from cookies stored on the browser vs what is used in the code, and impersonating the browser cookies seems to be the base of the fix. There was some debate about the right way to fix this (see [this theory](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/561#issuecomment-1462899426) tested in [an unmerged pull request](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/pull/563) and [another duplicate issue](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/566)).

Ultimately, **there was** [**a fix merged into the GitHub master on 8 April**](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/pull/570) (only a few days ago). [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/) was subsequently updated with [`v4.9.1`](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/4.9.1/) with the fix for this.

Except, surprise! [`v4.9.1` didn't include the merged fix](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/573#issuecomment-1503689831). So, as of **today**. they're working on releasing `v4.9.2` that actually fixes this issue. Until then, [one can install from GitHub](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/573#issuecomment-1503795706) to get this patch included in their installation. I haven't yet tried it, but `v4.9.2` supposedly works. Fingers crossed.

## Update: 14 April 2023

The [`pytrends`](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends) maintainers have now updated their documentation. The previously fixed issue in their code's compatibility with Google's updated API [was not yet in PyPi](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/573). On 13 April, they fixed this documentation error in [their bump to patch version 4.9.2](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/commit/220a5b7957de1476f110f89dabde2324aa5985a8). Note that as of now, this documentation bump exists in its own branch outside of `master`. This bump has been applied as [`v4.9.2` in PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/4.9.2/).

In my first test of my code with the updated installation of `pytrends`, this issue was fixed; everything worked flawlessly as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it the following way as per Github suggestion.

you need to override the TrendReq Library in your code and change the "Get" method to "Post" on the specific locations.

First of all copy the below class into your code:

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests import status_codes

from pytrends import exceptions

from urllib.parse import quote


BASE_TRENDS_URL = 'https://trends.google.com/trends'


class TrendReq(object):
    """
    Google Trends API
    """
    GET_METHOD = 'get'
    POST_METHOD = 'post'
    GENERAL_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/explore'
    INTEREST_OVER_TIME_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/widgetdata/multiline'
    MULTIRANGE_INTEREST_OVER_TIME_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/widgetdata/multirange'
    INTEREST_BY_REGION_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo'
    RELATED_QUERIES_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/widgetdata/relatedsearches'
    TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/hottrends/visualize/internal/data'
    TOP_CHARTS_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/topcharts'
    SUGGESTIONS_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/autocomplete/'
    CATEGORIES_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/explore/pickers/category'
    TODAY_SEARCHES_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/dailytrends'
    REALTIME_TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL = f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/api/realtimetrends'
    ERROR_CODES = (500, 502, 504, 429)

    def __init__(self, hl='en-US', tz=360, geo='', timeout=(2, 5), proxies='',
                 retries=0, backoff_factor=0, requests_args=None):
        """
        Initialize default values for params
        """
        # google rate limit
        self.google_rl = 'You have reached your quota limit. Please try again later.'
        self.results = None
        # set user defined options used globally
        self.tz = tz
        self.hl = hl
        self.geo = geo
        self.kw_list = list()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.proxies = proxies  # add a proxy option
        self.retries = retries
        self.backoff_factor = backoff_factor
        self.proxy_index = 0
        self.requests_args = requests_args or {}
        self.cookies = self.GetGoogleCookie()
        # intialize widget payloads
        self.token_payload = dict()
        self.interest_over_time_widget = dict()
        self.interest_by_region_widget = dict()
        self.related_topics_widget_list = list()
        self.related_queries_widget_list = list()

        self.headers = {'accept-language': self.hl}
        self.headers.update(self.requests_args.pop('headers', {}))
        
    def GetGoogleCookie(self):
        """
        Gets google cookie (used for each and every proxy; once on init otherwise)
        Removes proxy from the list on proxy error
        """
        while True:
            if "proxies" in self.requests_args:
                try:
                    return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.post(
                        f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/?geo={self.hl[-2:]}',
                        timeout=self.timeout,
                        **self.requests_args
                    ).cookies.items()))
                except:
                    continue
            else:
                if len(self.proxies) > 0:
                    proxy = {'https': self.proxies[self.proxy_index]}
                else:
                    proxy = ''
                try:
                    return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.post(
                        f'{BASE_TRENDS_URL}/?geo={self.hl[-2:]}',
                        timeout=self.timeout,
                        proxies=proxy,
                        **self.requests_args
                    ).cookies.items()))
                except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
                    print('Proxy error. Changing IP')
                    if len(self.proxies) > 1:
                        self.proxies.remove(self.proxies[self.proxy_index])
                    else:
                        print('No more proxies available. Bye!')
                        raise
                    continue

    def GetNewProxy(self):
        """
        Increment proxy INDEX; zero on overflow
        """
        if self.proxy_index < (len(self.proxies) - 1):
            self.proxy_index += 1
        else:
            self.proxy_index = 0

    def _get_data(self, url, method=GET_METHOD, trim_chars=0, **kwargs):
        """Send a request to Google and return the JSON response as a Python object
        :param url: the url to which the request will be sent
        :param method: the HTTP method ('get' or 'post')
        :param trim_chars: how many characters should be trimmed off the beginning of the content of the response
            before this is passed to the JSON parser
        :param kwargs: any extra key arguments passed to the request builder (usually query parameters or data)
        :return:
        """
        s = requests.session()
        # Retries mechanism. Activated when one of statements >0 (best used for proxy)
        if self.retries > 0 or self.backoff_factor > 0:
            retry = Retry(total=self.retries, read=self.retries,
                          connect=self.retries,
                          backoff_factor=self.backoff_factor,
                          status_forcelist=TrendReq.ERROR_CODES,
                          allowed_methods=frozenset(['GET', 'POST']))
            s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry))

        s.headers.update(self.headers)
        if len(self.proxies) > 0:
            self.cookies = self.GetGoogleCookie()
            s.proxies.update({'https': self.proxies[self.proxy_index]})
        if method == TrendReq.POST_METHOD:
            response = s.post(url, timeout=self.timeout,
                              cookies=self.cookies, **kwargs,
                              **self.requests_args)  # DO NOT USE retries or backoff_factor here
        else:
            response = s.get(url, timeout=self.timeout, cookies=self.cookies,
                             **kwargs, **self.requests_args)  # DO NOT USE retries or backoff_factor here
        # check if the response contains json and throw an exception otherwise
        # Google mostly sends 'application/json' in the Content-Type header,
        # but occasionally it sends 'application/javascript
        # and sometimes even 'text/javascript
        if response.status_code == 200 and 'application/json' in \
                response.headers['Content-Type'] or \
                'application/javascript' in response.headers['Content-Type'] or \
                'text/javascript' in response.headers['Content-Type']:
            # trim initial characters
            # some responses start with garbage characters, like ")]}',"
            # these have to be cleaned before being passed to the json parser
            content = response.text[trim_chars:]
            # parse json
            self.GetNewProxy()
            return json.loads(content)
        else:
            if response.status_code == status_codes.codes.too_many_requests:
                raise exceptions.TooManyRequestsError.from_response(response)
            raise exceptions.ResponseError.from_response(response)

    def build_payload(self, kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='',
                      gprop=''):
        """Create the payload for related queries, interest over time and interest by region"""
        if gprop not in ['', 'images', 'news', 'youtube', 'froogle']:
            raise ValueError('gprop must be empty (to indicate web), images, news, youtube, or froogle')
        self.kw_list = kw_list
        self.geo = geo or self.geo
        self.token_payload = {
            'hl': self.hl,
            'tz': self.tz,
            'req': {'comparisonItem': [], 'category': cat, 'property': gprop}
        }

        # Check if timeframe is a list
        if isinstance(timeframe, list):
            for index, kw in enumerate(self.kw_list):
                keyword_payload = {'keyword': kw, 'time': timeframe[index], 'geo': self.geo}
                self.token_payload['req']['comparisonItem'].append(keyword_payload)
        else: 
            # build out json for each keyword with
            for kw in self.kw_list:
                keyword_payload = {'keyword': kw, 'time': timeframe, 'geo': self.geo}
                self.token_payload['req']['comparisonItem'].append(keyword_payload)

        # requests will mangle this if it is not a string
        self.token_payload['req'] = json.dumps(self.token_payload['req'])
        # get tokens
        self._tokens()
        return

    def _tokens(self):
        """Makes request to Google to get API tokens for interest over time, interest by region and related queries"""
        # make the request and parse the returned json
        widget_dicts = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.GENERAL_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            params=self.token_payload,
            trim_chars=4,
        )['widgets']
        # order of the json matters...
        first_region_token = True
        # clear self.related_queries_widget_list and self.related_topics_widget_list
        # of old keywords'widgets
        self.related_queries_widget_list[:] = []
        self.related_topics_widget_list[:] = []
        # assign requests
        for widget in widget_dicts:
            if widget['id'] == 'TIMESERIES':
                self.interest_over_time_widget = widget
            if widget['id'] == 'GEO_MAP' and first_region_token:
                self.interest_by_region_widget = widget
                first_region_token = False
            # response for each term, put into a list
            if 'RELATED_TOPICS' in widget['id']:
                self.related_topics_widget_list.append(widget)
            if 'RELATED_QUERIES' in widget['id']:
                self.related_queries_widget_list.append(widget)
        return

    def interest_over_time(self):
        """Request data from Google's Interest Over Time section and return a dataframe"""

        over_time_payload = {
            # convert to string as requests will mangle
            'req': json.dumps(self.interest_over_time_widget['request']),
            'token': self.interest_over_time_widget['token'],
            'tz': self.tz
        }

        # make the request and parse the returned json
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.INTEREST_OVER_TIME_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=over_time_payload,
        )

        df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['default']['timelineData'])
        if (df.empty):
            return df

        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(dtype='float64'),
                                    unit='s')
        df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index()
        # split list columns into seperate ones, remove brackets and split on comma
        result_df = df['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
            str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')))
        # rename each column with its search term, relying on order that google provides...
        for idx, kw in enumerate(self.kw_list):
            # there is currently a bug with assigning columns that may be
            # parsed as a date in pandas: use explicit insert column method
            result_df.insert(len(result_df.columns), kw,
                             result_df[idx].astype('int'))
            del result_df[idx]

        if 'isPartial' in df:
            # make other dataframe from isPartial key data
            # split list columns into seperate ones, remove brackets and split on comma
            df = df.fillna(False)
            result_df2 = df['isPartial'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
                str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')))
            result_df2.columns = ['isPartial']
            # Change to a bool type.
            result_df2.isPartial = result_df2.isPartial == 'True'
            # concatenate the two dataframes
            final = pd.concat([result_df, result_df2], axis=1)
        else:
            final = result_df
            final['isPartial'] = False

        return final

    def multirange_interest_over_time(self):
        """Request data from Google's Interest Over Time section across different time ranges and return a dataframe"""

        over_time_payload = {
            # convert to string as requests will mangle
            'req': json.dumps(self.interest_over_time_widget['request']),
            'token': self.interest_over_time_widget['token'],
            'tz': self.tz
        }

        # make the request and parse the returned json
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.MULTIRANGE_INTEREST_OVER_TIME_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=over_time_payload,
        )

        df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['default']['timelineData'])
        if (df.empty):
            return df

        result_df = pd.json_normalize(df['columnData'])

        # Split dictionary columns into seperate ones
        for i, column in enumerate(result_df.columns):
            result_df["[" + str(i) + "] " + str(self.kw_list[i]) + " date"] = result_df[i].apply(pd.Series)["formattedTime"]
            result_df["[" + str(i) + "] " + str(self.kw_list[i]) + " value"] = result_df[i].apply(pd.Series)["value"]   
            result_df = result_df.drop([i], axis=1)
        
        # Adds a row with the averages at the top of the dataframe
        avg_row = {}
        for i, avg in enumerate(req_json['default']['averages']):
            avg_row["[" + str(i) + "] " + str(self.kw_list[i]) + " date"] = "Average"
            avg_row["[" + str(i) + "] " + str(self.kw_list[i]) + " value"] = req_json['default']['averages'][i]

        result_df.loc[-1] = avg_row
        result_df.index = result_df.index + 1
        result_df = result_df.sort_index()
        
        return result_df


    def interest_by_region(self, resolution='COUNTRY', inc_low_vol=False,
                           inc_geo_code=False):
        """Request data from Google's Interest by Region section and return a dataframe"""

        # make the request
        region_payload = dict()
        if self.geo == '':
            self.interest_by_region_widget['request'][
                'resolution'] = resolution
        elif self.geo == 'US' and resolution in ['DMA', 'CITY', 'REGION']:
            self.interest_by_region_widget['request'][
                'resolution'] = resolution

        self.interest_by_region_widget['request'][
            'includeLowSearchVolumeGeos'] = inc_low_vol

        # convert to string as requests will mangle
        region_payload['req'] = json.dumps(
            self.interest_by_region_widget['request'])
        region_payload['token'] = self.interest_by_region_widget['token']
        region_payload['tz'] = self.tz

        # parse returned json
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.INTEREST_BY_REGION_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=region_payload,
        )
        df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['default']['geoMapData'])
        if (df.empty):
            return df

        # rename the column with the search keyword
        geo_column = 'geoCode' if 'geoCode' in df.columns else 'coordinates'
        columns = ['geoName', geo_column, 'value']
        df = df[columns].set_index(['geoName']).sort_index()
        # split list columns into separate ones, remove brackets and split on comma
        result_df = df['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
            str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')))
        if inc_geo_code:
            if geo_column in df.columns:
                result_df[geo_column] = df[geo_column]
            else:
                print('Could not find geo_code column; Skipping')

        # rename each column with its search term
        for idx, kw in enumerate(self.kw_list):
            result_df[kw] = result_df[idx].astype('int')
            del result_df[idx]

        return result_df

    def related_topics(self):
        """Request data from Google's Related Topics section and return a dictionary of dataframes
        If no top and/or rising related topics are found, the value for the key "top" and/or "rising" will be None
        """

        # make the request
        related_payload = dict()
        result_dict = dict()
        for request_json in self.related_topics_widget_list:
            # ensure we know which keyword we are looking at rather than relying on order
            try:
                kw = request_json['request']['restriction'][
                    'complexKeywordsRestriction']['keyword'][0]['value']
            except KeyError:
                kw = ''
            # convert to string as requests will mangle
            related_payload['req'] = json.dumps(request_json['request'])
            related_payload['token'] = request_json['token']
            related_payload['tz'] = self.tz

            # parse the returned json
            req_json = self._get_data(
                url=TrendReq.RELATED_QUERIES_URL,
                method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
                trim_chars=5,
                params=related_payload,
            )

            # top topics
            try:
                top_list = req_json['default']['rankedList'][0]['rankedKeyword']
                df_top = pd.json_normalize(top_list, sep='_')
            except KeyError:
                # in case no top topics are found, the lines above will throw a KeyError
                df_top = None

            # rising topics
            try:
                rising_list = req_json['default']['rankedList'][1]['rankedKeyword']
                df_rising = pd.json_normalize(rising_list, sep='_')
            except KeyError:
                # in case no rising topics are found, the lines above will throw a KeyError
                df_rising = None

            result_dict[kw] = {'rising': df_rising, 'top': df_top}
        return result_dict

    def related_queries(self):
        """Request data from Google's Related Queries section and return a dictionary of dataframes
        If no top and/or rising related queries are found, the value for the key "top" and/or "rising" will be None
        """

        # make the request
        related_payload = dict()
        result_dict = dict()
        for request_json in self.related_queries_widget_list:
            # ensure we know which keyword we are looking at rather than relying on order
            try:
                kw = request_json['request']['restriction'][
                    'complexKeywordsRestriction']['keyword'][0]['value']
            except KeyError:
                kw = ''
            # convert to string as requests will mangle
            related_payload['req'] = json.dumps(request_json['request'])
            related_payload['token'] = request_json['token']
            related_payload['tz'] = self.tz

            # parse the returned json
            req_json = self._get_data(
                url=TrendReq.RELATED_QUERIES_URL,
                method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
                trim_chars=5,
                params=related_payload,
            )

            # top queries
            try:
                top_df = pd.DataFrame(
                    req_json['default']['rankedList'][0]['rankedKeyword'])
                top_df = top_df[['query', 'value']]
            except KeyError:
                # in case no top queries are found, the lines above will throw a KeyError
                top_df = None

            # rising queries
            try:
                rising_df = pd.DataFrame(
                    req_json['default']['rankedList'][1]['rankedKeyword'])
                rising_df = rising_df[['query', 'value']]
            except KeyError:
                # in case no rising queries are found, the lines above will throw a KeyError
                rising_df = None

            result_dict[kw] = {'top': top_df, 'rising': rising_df}
        return result_dict

    def trending_searches(self, pn='united_states'):
        """Request data from Google's Hot Searches section and return a dataframe"""

        # make the request
        # forms become obsolete due to the new TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL
        # forms = {'ajax': 1, 'pn': pn, 'htd': '', 'htv': 'l'}
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD
        )[pn]
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(req_json)
        return result_df

    def today_searches(self, pn='US'):
        """Request data from Google Daily Trends section and returns a dataframe"""
        forms = {'ns': 15, 'geo': pn, 'tz': '-180', 'hl': 'en-US'}
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.TODAY_SEARCHES_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=forms,
            **self.requests_args
        )['default']['trendingSearchesDays'][0]['trendingSearches']
        # parse the returned json
        result_df = pd.DataFrame(trend['title'] for trend in req_json)
        return result_df.iloc[:, -1]

    def realtime_trending_searches(self, pn='US', cat='all', count =300):
        """Request data from Google Realtime Search Trends section and returns a dataframe"""
        # Don't know what some of the params mean here, followed the nodejs library
        # https://github.com/pat310/google-trends-api/ 's implemenration


        #sort: api accepts only 0 as the value, optional parameter

        # ri: number of trending stories IDs returned,
        # max value of ri supported is 300, based on emperical evidence

        ri_value = 300
        if count < ri_value:
            ri_value = count

        # rs : don't know what is does but it's max value is never more than the ri_value based on emperical evidence
        # max value of ri supported is 200, based on emperical evidence
        rs_value = 200
        if count < rs_value:
            rs_value = count-1

        forms = {'ns': 15, 'geo': pn, 'tz': '300', 'hl': 'en-US', 'cat': cat, 'fi' : '0', 'fs' : '0', 'ri' : ri_value, 'rs' : rs_value, 'sort' : 0}
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.REALTIME_TRENDING_SEARCHES_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=forms
        )['storySummaries']['trendingStories']

        # parse the returned json
        wanted_keys = ["entityNames", "title"]

        final_json = [{ key: ts[key] for key in ts.keys() if key in wanted_keys} for ts in req_json ]

        result_df = pd.DataFrame(final_json)

        return result_df

    def top_charts(self, date, hl='en-US', tz=300, geo='GLOBAL'):
        """Request data from Google's Top Charts section and return a dataframe"""

        try:
            date = int(date)
        except:
            raise ValueError(
                'The date must be a year with format YYYY. See https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/355')

        # create the payload
        chart_payload = {'hl': hl, 'tz': tz, 'date': date, 'geo': geo,
                         'isMobile': False}

        # make the request and parse the returned json
        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.TOP_CHARTS_URL,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5,
            params=chart_payload
        )
        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame(req_json['topCharts'][0]['listItems'])
        except IndexError:
            df = None
        return df

    def suggestions(self, keyword):
        """Request data from Google's Keyword Suggestion dropdown and return a dictionary"""

        # make the request
        kw_param = quote(keyword)
        parameters = {'hl': self.hl}

        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.SUGGESTIONS_URL + kw_param,
            params=parameters,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5
        )['default']['topics']
        return req_json

    def categories(self):
        """Request available categories data from Google's API and return a dictionary"""

        params = {'hl': self.hl}

        req_json = self._get_data(
            url=TrendReq.CATEGORIES_URL,
            params=params,
            method=TrendReq.GET_METHOD,
            trim_chars=5
        )
        return req_json

    def get_historical_interest(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            """This method has been removed for incorrectness. It will be removed completely in v5.
If you'd like similar functionality, please try implementing it yourself and consider submitting a pull request to add it to pytrends.
          
There is discussion at:
https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/pull/542"""
        )
```

Locations where you need to change the code are:

```
return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.get(
```

Change this to:

```
return dict(filter(lambda i: i[0] == 'NID', requests.post(
```

Also remove the import reference for TrendReq as below

Remove this line from your code

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

The Method to call the TrendReq should look like something below

```
ptr = TrendReq(hl='en-AU',retries=3, backoff_factor=20)
kw_list = ["uber"]
ptr.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='US', gprop='')
pd = ptr.interest_over_time()
pd.reset_index(inplace = True)
df = pd[['uber']]
df.columns = ['Week','Uber']
```

This appears to be working for me now.